# 500 error when using htaccess rule for SEO Friendly URL for example.com/archive/?page=1

Tags: seo, htaccess, pagination

I'm trying to make `example.com/archive/?page=1` SEO friendly but every example I've tried, gives error 500. It might be because of the `index.php`.

Does anybody know how to make:

```
example.com/archive/?page=1
```

to look like:

```
example.com/archive/page/1/
```

Comment: What server are you using (Apache, IIS, Nginx)? If "every example gives a 500 error" then you might have something fundamentally missing on your server? Is mod_rewrite installed (Apache) for instance? Include an example you have tried. If you get a 500 error, you should look at your error log for the "real" error. "It might be because of the `index.php`" - What does `index.php` have to do with this? "SEO friendly" - Just to note, you make URLs "pretty" primarily for the user, not "SEO". Although an example such as this (pagination) is probably of no real benefit to the user anyway.

Comment: I have other rewriterules that are working. The latest I've tried was `RewriteRule ^archive/([^/]*)/$ /archive/?page=$1 [L]` which doesn't do anything.

Comment: You appear to be missing the "page" part from the _pattern_ in that last rule? However, it should do _something_ if the URL you type matches the pattern. Your mention of `index.php` suggests that you have a front controller (like WordPress uses)? The order of directives in .htaccess is important. If you add your entire `.htaccess` file to your question then we can get a better idea of what's going on, you might simply have a conflict with another rule.

Comment: So in my htaccess file, I've only put `RewriteEngine on` and `RewriteRule ^archive/page/([^/]*)/$ /archive/?page=$1 [L]` and it still dosn't work. The page is a static page with inline pagination. I have other rewiterules that work like `RewriteRule ^favicon.ico static/favicon.ico [L]`.

Comment: And by "doesn't work" you mean you get a 500 error? And the URL you are requesting is of the form `example.com/archive/page/1/`?

Comment: You need to figure out what is causing the 500 error.   Until you figure that out we are unlikely to be able to help you.   Your servers error_log file should have additional information.

Answer (score 1):

Even if there is small reconfiguration/typo-error in htaccess file, site goes down. If you have back-up of file try upload it. Always take back-up when you edit htaccess file.

*This code should work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule archive/page/(.*)$ http://example.com/archive/?page=$1
```

Comment: This will implicitly trigger an external (302) redirect, which defeats the point of the "pretty" URL (although this would be worth a test, to see if you get a result). However, neither will this match the URL in the request - you are missing a trailing slash. And you should include a start of string anchor (otherwise you could match too much).

Comment: Yes.It looks I missed the trailing slash. I didn't understand external (302) redirect. I really don't know how this triggers that.

Comment: If you specify an absolute URL (including scheme and hostname) in the `RewriteRule` _substitution_ then mod_rewrite _implicitly_ triggers an external redirect as opposed to an internal rewrite (despite not _explicitly_ including the `R` flag). (The docs are a bit misleading in this respect as they seem to suggest that the scheme and hostname are simply stripped if they match the current scheme and hostname - this does not appear to be the case in per-directory rewrites.)

Comment: However, the OP (in comments) already states they have tried something like this but it still "doesn't work" - so there would seem to be something more to the puzzle?